# How to create libraries for Dart?

Tags: dart, dartium

How can I create libraries using Dart?

I want to start porting some JavaScript (and other languages) libraries I've created to Dart.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just put this in your library file (first place):

```
library mylibraryname;
```

You can then import this lib with:

```
import "path/to/mylibraryname.dart";
```

Other options are available, for example `part` which acts as include.

For a more in-depth tutorial I recommend you this [blog post from Dartwatch](http://blog.dartwatch.com/2011/10/exploring-dart-libraries-organizing.html).

Comment: Must the library file name match its declared library name?  For example, if I declare "libary foo" in a file, must the file be named "foo.dart"?

Comment: Link appears to be dead :(

Answer (score 1):

[stagehand](https://pub.dev/packages/stagehand) is the most simply.

### Usage

```
mkdir fancy_project
cd fancy_project
stagehand package-simple
```

### Stagehand templates

```
console-full - A command-line application sample.
package-simple - A starting point for Dart libraries or applications.
server-shelf - A web server built using the shelf package.
web-angular - A web app with material design components.
web-simple - A web app that uses only core Dart libraries.
web-stagexl - A starting point for 2D animation and games.
```

### Installation

If you want to use Stagehand on the command line, install it using pub global activate:

```
pub global activate stagehand
```

Comment: This project (stagehand) has been discontinued.