# Use dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType instead inheritFromWidgetOfExactType for flutter constants best practices

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement best practices for constants in Flutter by Rémi Rousselet's: [What's the best practice to keep all the constants in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069239)

but `inheritFromWidgetOfExactType` is deprecated:

> 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. 
>   Use dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType instead. 
>   This feature was deprecated after v1.12.1..
>   Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.

Could you help me to implement that with `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType`?

Comment: I've updated the answer to make it work with the new method instead

Comment: Thanks! i couldn't comment because of reputation. But it still have an error: 'MyConstants.updateShouldNotify' ('bool Function()') isn't a valid override of 'InheritedWidget.updateShouldNotify' ('bool Function(InheritedWidget)').

Comment: Oopsy, fixed too.

Answer (score 6):

I use in my class `Provider extends InheritedWidget` like this

```
static Bloc of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Provider>().bloc;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example of a replacement**:

```
// Before, We write :
 context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(Name) as Name;

// Now instead of taking a Type as argument, The method is a generic.
  context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Name>();
```

---

A snippet of using the **[dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType.html)  method**

```
 static Name of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Name>();
  }
```