# Flutter global variables

Tags: flutter, dart

my question is about global variables. I think I have never seen variables declared outside of classes. My question is: why?

For my small projects I often created variables simply like that:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

String title = 'this is title';
String userName = '';

StatefulWidget...
```

It always worked for me to easy use them

Comment: It is purely opinion and style.  A lot of people who have worked in software for a considerable amount of time have found that this type of declaration can lead to a number of issues, especially on larger projects.  Therefore, it is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Because normally global parameters are mostly used for constants.

> Non-const global variables are evil because their value can be changed by any function. Using global variables reduces the modularity and flexibility of the program

[Are global variables bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad)

As for where to put constants, there are few sugestions:
[What's the best practice to keep all the constants in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069239/whats-the-best-practice-to-keep-all-the-constants-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Create `Constant.dart` file and set all variable to call globally like below,

```
// string
final title = 'this is title';
// image
final backButton = new AssetImage("assets/arrowLeft.png");
```

Import the package/path of constant file to file which need to use,

```
import 'package:projectName/Helper/Common.dart';
```

Finally, call the variable or any image/constant name,

```
image: DecorationImage(
       image:backButton,// here is global constant name..
       fit:BoxFit.cover
   ),
```