# What is more efficient way to use normal const in file and static const in a class file in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is more efficient way to use normal const in file and  static const in a class file in dart?
`const MARGIN_SMALL = 4.0;`
and

```
class AppDimen {
  const MARGIN_SMALL = 4.0;
}
```

Comment: there is no hard and fast rule please check out the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069239/whats-the-best-practice-to-keep-all-the-constants-in-flutter) and [effective dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design)

Comment: There would be no difference in performance.