# What is the best convention to store colors and icons in my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

What is the best way to store colors in the flutter application?
currently, it looks like this: (is that a good way?)

I would like to know the best way

Example of colors:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color orange = Color(0xFFFF6C00);

const Color purple1 = Color(0xFF7B1FA2);
```

Example of icons:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const IconData checkIcon = Icons.check;

const IconData maleIcon = Icons.male;

const IconData femaleIcon = Icons.female;
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: It's opinion based.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069239/whats-the-best-practice-to-keep-all-the-constants-in-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a separate file named `constants.dart` to store all your constants.
You should also name each constant with a preface with the letter `K`, so it's easier to find when using your IDE's auto-suggestions - you just need to type in the letter <kbd>K</kbd>.

for example, in your `constants.dart` file:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const IconData KcheckIcon = Icons.check;

const IconData KmaleIcon = Icons.male;

const IconData KfemaleIcon = Icons.female;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a class that includes all you custom colors or icons you use, so you just call them like "AppColors.red100" or " AppIcons.heart"